# Return pointer of one of the child classes from a function

Tags: c++

I have an abstract `Parent` class and a bunch of child classes, `ChildA`, `ChildB`, `ChildC` which inherits `Parent`.

Inside a class, `Container`, it stores a unique pointer to `ChildA`, `ChildB`, and `ChildC`. I have a function `foo(type)` which takes in an enum (maps to one of the child classes) and returns a pointer to one of the child classes. I would like to do something like

```
if (type == 0) {
   return childAPtr;
} else if (type == 1) {
   return childBPtr;
} else {
   return childCPtr;
}
```

However, I am having trouble defining the return type of `foo`. What is the ideal way to handle such a case? I have also thought of using a map of `type` to the child classes, but map requires 2 types in its template arguments and I am not sure how to define the second type.

TIA!

Comment: What about `Parent*`?

Comment: `Parent` is a virtual class so it can't be the return type. 
U

Comment: Sure, but a pointer or reference to it can. That's the whole point of polymorphism.

Comment: Your inheritance indicates that a child is a parent, publicly deriving forms an "is a" relationship. I'd suggest you drop parent/child and use base/derived instead, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: You might want to refresh the chapters about inheritance and polymorphism in your text books.

Comment: *"thought of using a map of type to the child classes, but map requires 2 types in its template arguments and I am not sure how to define the second type"* `std::unique_ptr<Base>`?

Comment: I've managed to store the `unique_ptr`s in a `map` and now foo's return type is `Parent&`. I did not use `Parent*` because it prompts that there is no user-defined conversion between the parent and child class. However, after retrieving the `Parent&` from `foo`, the compiler prompts that the function declared in `Parent` and defined in `Child` is abstract.

Comment: You should probably delete this questions, then take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And especially learn how to create a [mre]. Then please post a better question where all the details are known from the start.

Comment: Also note, returning references is sometimes not going to work very well, if you return references to local objects. And don't attempt to copy into `Parent` objects, that's not possible if `Parent` is abstract. Instead continue to use pointers to references.

Comment: Lastly a note about the pattern shown in the code you show here: That's often an *anti* pattern.